# Programmatically determine the associativity of an L1 cache

Tags: c, algorithm, caching, cpu-cache

I searched for similar questions; one was similar but there wasn't a definitive answer.

I can write a C program to determine both the line length and size of a cache but I can't think of a way to determine its associativity. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does your C program determine these things statistically or by asking some all-knowing library?  Because, if you can figure out cache line length statistically, you can probably also figure out associativity statistically.

Comment: @tmyklebu, statistically by varying candidate stride and cache size. How would I determine associativity statistically, on a conceptual level?

Comment: Also, @tmyklebu, if it was yourself that downvoted my question, please could you tell me the reason(s) so that I can improve my future questions (and this one by editing it)?

Comment: I didn't.  You could determine associativity by seeing what happens when you hammer increasing numbers of associated cache lines.  When it gets slow, you're one past the limit.

Comment: Fair enough, must have been someone else then... I found a paper that I think describes what you're saying but I need to check I've understood this right: (Section 3.3.1: [link](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=osu1308256764&disposition=inline)). So, if I know the cache size and line length (having previously determined them), I double the stride, initially set to the line length, and measure the time taken for an increasing number of locations to be read to jump, until the number of locations read before a jump settles at the level of associativity?

Comment: That Master's thesis seems to be doing a way better job than I would have done.  The observable artefact of (say 8-way) cache associativity is that repeated accesses of 9 (or 16) cache lines belonging to the same set see higher latency than repeated accesses of 9 (or 16) cache lines belonging to different sets, whereas hammering on 8 cache lines in the same set sees the same latency as hammering on 8 cache lines in different sets.  So hammer on 9 lines in the same set and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That's brilliant, thanks @tmyklebu! Do you want to put that as an answer so that I can mark it as 'accepted'?

Comment: Ask and you shall receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable artefact of a k-way associative cache is that k+1 accesses to the same set will cause an eviction.  Thus you will see a marked difference in accesses-per-second between hammering on k cache lines in a tight loop and hammering on k+1 cache lines in a tight loop.  There will also be a performance difference between hammering on k+1 cache lines in a set in a tight loop and hammering on k+1 cache lines, not all in a set, in a tight loop.

You linked me to [Varadharajan Chandran's Master's thesis](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=osu1308256764&disposition=inline), which does something like this (and much more) in order to infer lots of characteristics of both the processor cache and the TLB.

Comment: Link is dead :)